# Run only proxy on server

Tags: proxy

I have 5 servers which are in a private domain. 1 server has a public IP.
I've installed a proxy server on that server and I let the other 4 servers connect to that proxy server.

The 4 servers need environment variables + some configuration to use the proxy server which is fine.

But the server on which I've installed the proxy server still has that public ip of course so I'm still able to perform "`sudo apt-get install xxx`" without specifying the proxy variables.

Did I forget some configuration or is this a normal approach? So should I only install a proxy on that server and all the rest on the other 4 servers.

Answer (score 0):

Specifically for apt-get, I would set *all* servers to use the proxy, so that they can all potentially pull packages from cache rather than from the network.

Other than that, your setup sounds totally fine to me - and yes, that approach/config seems normal to me (how meaningful, or re-assuring, that might be is a matter for debate).

Comment: As far as I remember in network settings you can add feature" send all traffic over VPN/Proxy connection" I guess it might help.